# Do I need to enclose ANSI escape sequences in \[ and \] in a bash prompt?

Tags: bash, prompt

I want to customize my bash prompt using ANSI escape codes and have noticed that in some howtos the codes are enclosed in `\[` and `\]` while in others they aren't.

For example, these work equally well for me:

```
PS1='\e[0;32m foo '
PS1='\[\e[0;32m\] foo '
```

I wonder what difference does it make?

Comment: Please don't [cross-post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067166/using-ansi-escape-sequences-in-bash-prompt).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The difference is that in the ones without `\[` and `\]`, bash will be unable to track the real length of the prompt and various visual glitches will reveal themselves over time.

Answer (score 6):

It's explained nicely on this [page](http://www.funtoo.org/en/articles/linux/tips/prompt/):

> These sequences will tell bash that
>   the enclosed characters don't take up
>   any space on the line, which will
>   allow word-wrapping to continue to
>   work properly. Without them, you'll
>   end up with a nice-looking prompt that
>   will mess up the screen if you happen
>   to type in a command that approaches
>   the extreme right of the terminal.